# Integrating $\int \frac{e^x}{\sqrt{e^{2x}-1}}dx$ with $u$-substitution only

Tags: calculus, integration

I am trying to integrate this with $u$-substitution only
$$\int \frac{e^x}{\sqrt{e^{2x}-1}}dx$$

I looked at my book's answer key and played around with it a bit, but I'm still very confused.

I know I should choose $u$ to be ${\sqrt{e^{2x}-1}}$

When I differentiate that, I get $$\frac{e^{2x}}{\sqrt{e^{2x}-1}}$$

I get lost here, especially with the numerator. Also is there another $u$ value I can choose?

Comment: What's the issue with this choice of $u$? You should stick with this choice of $u$.

Comment: What specifically are you getting lost on with the numerator?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With $u = \sqrt{e^{2x} - 1}$, you have $e^x = \sqrt{u^2 + 1}$. Then

$$du = \frac{e^{2x}}{\sqrt{e^{2x} - 1}} dx = \frac{u^2 + 1}{u}du \implies dx = \frac{u}{u^2 + 1} du$$

Then

$$\int \frac{e^x}{\sqrt{e^{2x} - 1}} dx = \int \frac{\sqrt{u^2 + 1}}{u} \cdot \frac{u}{u^2 + 1} du = \int \frac{1}{\sqrt{u^2 + 1}}du$$

so I'm not exactly seeing where the issue lies with that substitution; maybe a miscalculation on your part? This seems to match the form of integral $(32)$ on [this reference sheet I have bookmarked,](http://integral-table.com/downloads/single-page-integral-table.pdf) on the off chance it's actually a form you're unfamiliar with (though the answer is more succinctly sometimes seen in terms of hyperbolic arccosine).

The result would be, regardless,

$$\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{u^2 + 1}}du = \ln \left| u + \sqrt{u^2 + 1} \right| + C = \cosh^{-1}(\sqrt{u^2 + 1}) + C$$

and then you just bring back in your $u$. This gives $\sqrt{e^{2x} - 1} + e^x$ inside the logarithm and thus

$$\int \frac{e^x}{\sqrt{e^{2x} - 1}} dx = \ln \left| e^x + \sqrt{e^{2x} + 1} \right| + C = \cosh^{-1}(e^x) +C$$

---

Footnote: Peter Foreman's answer reaches the same conclusion, and is just as valid. You could use either $u$-substitution, whichever you think is easier to contend with.

Answer (score 5):

Using $u=e^x$, $du=e^xdx$ so the integral is equal to
$$\int \frac{du}{\sqrt{u^2-1}}=\cosh^{-1}{(u)}+c$$
$$\therefore \int\frac{e^x}{\sqrt{e^{2x}-1}}dx=\cosh^{-1}{(e^x)}+c$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\text{Let }\begin{bmatrix}u \\ \mathrm du\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}e^x\\e^x\mathrm dx\end{bmatrix}\implies \int\dfrac{e^x}{\sqrt{e^{2x}-1}}\mathrm dx=\int\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{u^2-1}}\mathrm du$$

As has been already illustrated by @EeveeTrainer and @PeterForeman the techniques of u-substitution and knowing-the-derivative-of $\cosh^{-1}x$. So, I would present another way to tackle this using trig-substitution.

$$\text{Let }\begin{bmatrix}u\\\mathrm du\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}\sec\theta\\\sec\theta\tan\theta\mathrm d\theta\end{bmatrix}\implies \int \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{u^2-1}}\mathrm du=\int \dfrac{\sec\theta\tan\theta}{\sec\theta}\mathrm d\theta$$

Can you proceed?